# libsvm: optimization finished, #iter = 1 nu = nan

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I use libsvm to train a svm model in matlab, but when I call

```
model = svmtrain(labels,Feature,'-t 0');
```

It gives me this result:

```
*
optimization finished, #iter = 1
nu = nan
obj = nan, rho = nan
nSV = 0, nBSV = 0
Total nSV = 0
```

My positive and negative samples are of almost equal number: 935 vs 904 so this problem is not caused by unbalanced training dataset. Also I tried other kernels and none of them work.

Comment: Just as an  afterthought, doesnt '-t 0' set the maximum number of iterations to zero? Or is that a different name-value pair? Im not that familiar with svmtrain alas. Good the new toolbox worked.

Comment: '-t 0' means choosing linear kernel, you can find this in https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to use `svmtrain` any more. The new version is [`templatesvm`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/templatesvm.html) paired with [`fitcecoc`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcecoc.html). The datapages on both functions are quite extensive.

You'll eventually want to use your model to predict other data, use [`predict`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/compactclassificationecoc.predict.html) for that.

I recently encoutered similar problems when trying to classify terrain in a point cloud with more than two classes. `templatesvm` and `fitcecoc` solved my problems.

The code I used is as follows, where `trainingdata` is my 5 dimensional training data and `groups` contains the label for each class, which correspond to the cell array `classes`.

```
SVMtemp = templateSVM('KernelFunction','polynomial','IterationLimit',1e4,...
    'PolynomialOrder',4,'OutlierFraction',ExpOut,...
    'Standardize',true); % Create SVM template
Model =     fitcecoc(trainingdata(:,4:8),groups,'learners',SVMtemp,'ClassNames',...
    classes); % Create the SVM model
```

Comment: Is this statistics and machine learning toolbox available for matlab 2013?

Comment: The toolbox is available, but the fitcecoc and predict functions are not until 2014a:
http://mathworks.com/help/stats/release-notes.html